# Variable in an attribute in Struts custom tag

Tags: struts

I am trying to use a variable inside a custom Struts tag something like follows -

```
for(String currentMacro : (List<String>)(request.getAttribute("individualMacros"))) {
    name = currentMacro.<some-operation>

<html:mce name = "hmtl_<%= name %>" />
```

Something like this. But <%=name%> is not replaced with the variable value. It works when I am using the variable with a pure HTML tags.

Is there any any way to accomplish this in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSP EL (assuming JSP 2.0, and you put "name" into scope). You could also check to the if the TLD allows rtexprs.

`<html:mce name="html_${name}"/>`

But why use scriptlets? There's rarely (ever?) a good reason.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I put Java variables in the scope so as to use it as you had mentioned?

Comment: With `request.setAttribute("name", name);`

Comment: Good deal :) Although I'd really recommend avoiding scriptlets.

Comment: The scenario is like this - I process a text to split it into meaningful parts and put this in a list and put this list as a request attribute and then the control is sent to a JSP page in which I iterate over the list and make some html (using custom tags - in which the attributes specifically name are in the list). I can't really understand how to do it otherwise. If you have any idea, please share. I'll be happy to consider. Thanks.

Comment: Use JSTL's `<c:forEach>` (or S1's `<logic:iterate>`, but in general, when JSTL functionality overlaps S1's custom tags, use JSTL).

Comment: Dave - I tried using `<c:forEach>` but it does not work. In my case, I was using `for(String currentMacro : (List<String>)(request.getAttribute("individualMacros")))` which I tried to change to `<c:forEach var = "currentMacro" items = "${individualMacros}">`. It does not work and I get and error in the logs which say - "According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute items does not accept any expressions". How to make this work?

Comment: Are you using a container that supports JSP 2.0? Is your web app configured to the correct servlet spec revision?

Comment: Ok. I figured out. I was using the taglib uri of JSTL 1.0 instead of JSTL 1.1. Having corrected that, it now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are taking about a custom tag, my guess is that in the [TLD](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tutorial/TagLibraries9.html) file there isn't the `rtexprvalue` option set to true for that particular tag attribute:

```
<attribute>
   <name>name</name>
   <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
   .......
</attribute>
```

The `rtexprvalue` specifies that the attribute value may be dynamically evaluated at runtime.

If set to "false" it means that the attribute has a static value which is evaluated at [translation](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro4.html); if set to "true" it means the value can be determined dynamically at runtime. Default is "false".

If the scriptlet does not work, it most likely means `rtexprvalue` is false. If you don't have the liberty to change that, then expressions won't work on that particular attribute.

Comment: I tried doing that but it still does not work. The <%= %> in the name does not evaluate - <html:richeditor name="html_<%=name %>" />.