# Pass string variable to struts tag

Tags: struts

I want to pass a string variable to an struts tag.

```
alert('<bean:message key="${result}"/>');
```

This tag is responsible to extract message from ApplicationResources.properties. Result contains the key for this message. the system tries to use the same result string itself rather than its content. Here is the error I get.

"Missing message for key "${result}"

I see this question and I got an idea but the problem still exist.
[Variable in an attribute in Struts custom tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389308/variable-in-an-attribute-in-struts-custom-tag)

My application is base on struts.

I use sth like this but I think its ugly and smelly

```
    if(result == 'a.b.c' )
        alert('<bean:message key="a.b.c"/>');
    else if(result == 'a.b.c' )
        alert('<bean:message key="a.b.d"/>');
    else if(result == 'a.b.d' )
        alert('<bean:message key="a.b.d"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
alert('<bean:message name="result"/>');
```

http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-bean.html#message

Comment: I tried it the first time. The problem is that Java script or strusts try to retrieve a string with name of result instead of using the content of result which point to an entry in app.properties. I use sth like this but I think its ugly and smelly

        if(result == 'a.b.c' )
            alert('<bean:message key="a.b.c"/>');
        else if(result == 'a.b.c' )
            alert('<bean:message key="a.b.d"/>');
        else if(result == 'a.b.d' )
            alert('<bean:message key="a.b.d"/>');